# How to iterate over a vector of strings and use switch case in matlab?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, vector, switch-statement

I am new to matlab (few minutes old!). I have a vector of strings as:

```
methods = {'adaptiveMixtureDiscriminantAnalysis',
          'gamSpline',
          'genaralizedPartialLeastSquares'
          'penalizedMultinomialRegression',
          'quadraticDiscriminantAnalysis'}
```

I am using a `switch-case` construct as follows:

```
for training_method = methods

    switch training_method
        case 'adaptiveMixtureDiscriminantAnalysis' 
            evalR('signal_and_conf <- adaptiveMixtureDiscriminantAnalysis(train_predictors, train_labels, test_predictors)');
        case 'gamSpline'
            evalR('signal_and_conf <- gamSpline(train_predictors, train_labels, test_predictors)');
        case 'genaralizedPartialLeastSquares'
            evalR('signal_and_conf <- genaralizedPartialLeastSquares(train_predictors, train_labels, test_predictors)');
        case 'penalizedMultinomialRegression'
            evalR('signal_and_conf <- penalizedMultinomialRegression(train_predictors, train_labels, test_predictors)');
        case 'quadraticDiscriminantAnalysis'
            evalR('signal_and_conf <- quadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(train_predictors, train_labels, test_predictors)');
        case 'majorityVoting'
            evalR('signal_and_conf <- majorityVoting(train_predictors, train_labels, test_predictors)');
        otherwise
            disp('No such model is available!')
    end

end
```

But it gives me an error saying `SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant.`

I also tried using `cellstr()` for `training_method` and also using `[training_method]` in switch construct but still no luck.

**Update:**

All I had to do was changing `training_method` to `char(training_method)` in switch statement and it worked. I am still confused with `cell` and `char` datatypes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element `training_method` in your `for` loop would be a cell array of a single element.  You can only use `switch` with an actual character array or integer literals, so you need to unpack the cell by either doing `training_method{1}`, or `char(training_method)` as you have stated in your update.

As such, do either:

```
for training_method = methods

    switch training_method{1}

    ....
```

Or:

```
for training_method = methods

    switch char(training_method) %// Already done by you

    ....
```

Comment: "unpack the cell": well put!